# Is it possible to hardcode your application to (for example) always use scaletype: Centercrop when you add imageviews in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

As the title states I was wondering if it is possible to hardcode certain elements in your project like for example what I stated in the title.
This could be highly useful if you are using centercrop for imageviews all the time, not to mention all the other options there are!

I am hoping there are more people who are wondering the same and maybe even some people who actually already do it or know how I would have to ... around with the code to get it to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attributes like this in your `AppTheme` in `styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
```

Comment: Damn I should've known there was an easy way out like this, thanks!